# One Son By One Woman

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, usage

I have a question about the usage of "*by*" and "*with*".  Let's say that a guy had a relationship with a woman and a daughter was born.  That relationship ended, and then he had another relationship with a different woman and a son was born.

> 1. He has one son ***with*** one woman, and a daughter ***with*** another woman.
> 2. He has one son ***by*** one woman, and a daughter **by** another woman.

The first sentence, using "*with*" is definitely standard English.  The second sentence, using "*by*" is found on the web.  Could it be wrong?  What do native speakers think?  If usage of "*by*" is standard English, then, is it more formal than "*with*"?

Comment: They're both correct English. I think that 'by' *might* be a more formal version, but I'm not sure.

Comment: **19. begot or born of: She had a son by her first husband.** _by. (n.d.) Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. (2010). Retrieved July 27 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/by_

Comment: **By** has been in use far longer than **with** in this context. It is more formal than **with**, in the sense that in a boilerplate legal document relating to an inheritance, say, or in a formulaic obituary, you'd be more likely to find **by** not **with**.

Comment: 'By' is often used in animal husbandry, especially concerning horses.

Comment: When used in animal husbandry, it usually only refers to the father; the mother is "out of". We don't use "out of" with humans.

Answer (score 0):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/by)

> **by** (preposition) (AGENT) = used to show the person or thing that does something
>
> - The book was translated **by** a well-known author.

---

> He has one son **with** one woman, and a daughter **with** another woman.

The meaning is straightforward and unambiguous: the man and the two women "united" and therefore they had children. The (biological) parents are clearly known.

---

> He has one son **by** one woman, and a daughter **by** another woman.

In this case, the meaning is:

- explicit: the man now has 2 children;
- explicit: the 2 women gave birth to the children; they are the means of delivering the children;
- implicit **but not guaranteed**: the 3 persons are the biological parents.

In this case, the 2 women may have been his wives (consecutively, as explained), but there is a chance that the father(s) of the children is not the man presented in the story.

Answer (score -1):

Using both "with" and "by" have the understanding of who the two parents are in your example and when two people are mentioned the terms can be interchanged, though "with" usually gets used more often and has a feeling of relationship

> He had a son with his first wife.
>   With his wife, they have four children.

"By" has a more "clinical" feeling in its usage and is used to convey "how" *something* happened

> They had a child by *in vitro* fertilisation.
>   She was made pregnant by her boyfriend.
>   They have a child by adoption.